# How to sort data based on two columns by grouping on one column among them?

Tags: sql, sorting

I have the following set of data.
select * from STATEMENT_HISTORY(nolock) order by stmt_dte desc

```
stmt_key          stmt_dte                stmt_start_dte          stmt_end_dte
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
12          2013-10-13 00:00:00.000 2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 2013-08-10 00:00:00.000
11          2013-10-12 00:00:00.000 2013-03-10 00:00:00.000 2013-04-10 00:00:00.000
10          2013-10-11 00:00:00.000 2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 2013-08-10 00:00:00.000                
9           2013-10-10 00:00:00.000 2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 2013-10-10 00:00:00.000
8           2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 2013-08-10 00:00:00.000 2013-09-10 00:00:00.000
7           2013-08-10 00:00:00.000 2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 2013-08-10 00:00:00.000
6           2013-07-10 00:00:00.000 2013-06-10 00:00:00.000 2013-07-10 00:00:00.000
5           2013-06-10 00:00:00.000 2013-05-10 00:00:00.000 2013-06-10 00:00:00.000
4           2013-05-10 00:00:00.000 2013-04-10 00:00:00.000 2013-05-10 00:00:00.000
3           2013-04-10 00:00:00.000 2013-03-10 00:00:00.000 2013-04-10 00:00:00.000
2           2013-03-10 00:00:00.000 2013-02-10 00:00:00.000 2013-03-10 00:00:00.000
1           2013-02-10 00:00:00.000 2013-01-10 00:00:00.000 2013-02-10 00:00:00.000
```

My requirement is as follows.
1. The row with latest stmt_dte should be on top
2. All other rows that match with the stmt_start_dte of the top row should take next place sorted by stmt_dte among them and so on.

Expected output should be in the following order.

```
stmt_key
--------
12
10
7
11
3
10
9
8
6
5
4
2
1
```

How do I achieve it? Can some one suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using SQL Server.  The logic appears to be:

- Keep the records with the same `stmt_start_dte` together
- Order them by the maximum `stmt_dte`

You can do this by using the `max()` window function:

```
select stmt_key, stmt_dte, stmt_start_dte, stmt_end_dte
from (select sh.*, max(stmt_dte) over (partition by stmt_start_dte) as grp
      from STATEMENT_HISTORY sh
     ) sh
order by grp desc, stmt_dte desc;
```